# Chromium Embedded (CEF) - Splash Screen

Tags: splash-screen, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm modifying a cefsimple app to meet my needs. I have a long starting thread at the background so it takes a while until the web page is shown (5-10 secs). In the meanwhile I want to show some kind of splash screen, or at least some HTML before the main page is rendered. What's the best (or any) way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We have an html file compiled into our application and we pass that URL to CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowserSync().

See resource_util_win.cpp in cefclient sample, in particular GetResourceId() for associating the URL to the compiled resource ID.

Meanwhile, the body of our splashscreen.html has

```
<body class="splash" onload=" pageLoad() ">
```

and the pageLoad() looks like

```
        function pageLoad() {
            window.location = "www.yourrealurl.com";
            }          
        }
```

Our splash screen has a background set by style sheet and an animated gif, and it goes away as soon as the requested url comes in.

If you have already gotten the server response but it takes a long time to render, this won't help.  We use Angular in the loaded page to hide it until it is finished loading its dependencies.

```
<div ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" ng-if="IsInitDone()">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It already give me a very good idea, but if you don't mind could you please give a bit more details, maybe with code examples (sorry I'm completely new to CEF and coming from a Java world). For example, how do you read and pass splashscreen.html. What happens if a server (actually embedded JVM) does not yet reply on www.yourrealurl.com, but will after a couple of seconds? Thanks!

Comment: what platform are you on?

Comment: On windows we have the SplashScreen.html, the animated.gif and the site.css style sheet compiled into the app as standard windows resources.

Comment: argh, timeout in edit.  I was incorrect about GetResourceHandle() in my answer (I've edited it), what you want to do is the same thing the cefclient sample does in resource_util_win.cpp, see their GetResourceId() and LoadBinaryResource() functions.

Comment: if your embedded JVM does not reply for several seconds, you should be fine if the response is complete - the splash screen should remain visible until the page you load from the splash screen loads. If you deliver partial results you may want to hold responding until all of the data is available.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I managed to embed an html page and an animated gif, and they are loaded fine. However, I still have a delay before the "splash" page is loaded. The reason for it is probably that CEF waits for JVM to be initialised. What I'm doing is: creating a JVM from ClientHandler constructor (actually the creation method executes CefPostTask for TID_PROCESS_LAUNCHER), then in the same thread I launch a main method of my web service. What would be the right way of launching a JVM that a) takes some time to start; b) it takes a bit after the start to begin to respond to requests?

Comment: How about if you have the onLoad() in the splash screen body call into some Javascript in your client to actually start the JVM, instead of starting it explicitly in the client?  So add something like window.startJVM(); to that pageLoad() function in the answer.  Of course  you'll have to set up the JS  methods in the CEF client, but you are probably already doing some of those, if not it isn't hard, it is well documented in the CEF docs.